# Can you target a widget_class in a register_sidebar?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, twitter-bootstrap, register-sidebar

Using Bootstrap 3 to create a WordPress theme I am using `register_sidebar()` for the sidebar:

```
if ( function_exists( 'register_sidebar' ) ) {
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Some Sidebar', 'theTheme' ),
        'id'            => 'some-sidebar',
        'description'   => __( 'An optional custom widget area for the sidebar', 'theTheme' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">',
        'after_widget'  => "</div>",
    ));
}
```

I would like to control the `before_widget` results on a register sidebar level instead of hard coding everything into the `widget()` so I can use:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args[ 'before_widget' ];
    echo $args[ 'after_widget' ];
}
```

I thought I could target the `widget_class` but that doesn't work:

```
if ( register_widget( 'some_widget' ) ) {
    'before_widget' => '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 hidden-md col-lg-3">',
    'after_widget'  => "</div>",
else {
    'before_widget' => '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">',
    'after_widget'  => "</div>",
}
```

I can do this if I do not use `before_widget` and `after_widget` but I'm trying to work on my DRY practices.  I've done a lot of research with no results, the codex is minimal and the forums produce no results so is there a better way to do this without hard coding into the `widget()`?